# XSLT1 fo replacing placeholders

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0, xsl-fo

I have to replace some placeholder like $$RUOLO^ with a xpath, this is the result xsl:fo:

```
 <fo:block>e per il ruolo $$RUOLO^ , funzione <xsl:value-of xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/FUNZIONE_BREVE"/> da lei ricoperta per la specifica informazione con la seguente motivazione $$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^ .</fo:block>
```

I have replaced $$FUNZIONE^ with  select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/FUNZIONE_BREVE"/> but this dosent happen for RUOLO. Why not?

This is like I do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo fn xsl XWC" 
xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
xmlns:XWC="http://www.netbureau.it/XWC/2.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<!-- non toccare -->
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- fine non toccare -->

<!-- match templates per sostituzione variabili-->

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$EVENTO^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$EVENTO^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="eventotmp"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$DECORRENZA^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$DECORRENZA^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="decorrenzatmp">
            <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="descrizionetmp">
            <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$TIPOLOGIA_INFORMAZIONE_PRIVILEGIATA^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$TIPOLOGIA_INFORMAZIONE_PRIVILEGIATA^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="tipologiatmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$RUOLO^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$RUOLO^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="ruolotmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$FUNZIONE^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$FUNZIONE^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="funzionetmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$NR_ARTICOLO^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$NR_ARTICOLO^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="nrarticolotmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$CODICE_INFORMAZIONE^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$CODICE_INFORMAZIONE^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="codinfotmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$CIP^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$CIP^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="ciptmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$PROTOCOLLO^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$PROTOCOLLO^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="protocollotmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$EMITTENTE^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$EMITTENTE^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="emittentetmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(text(),'$$AREA_COMPETENZA^')] | fo:inline[contains(text(),'$$AREA_COMPETENZA^')]">
        <xsl:call-template  name="areacompetenzatmp">
        <xsl:with-param name="text"><xsl:value-of select="text()"/></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:template>




<!-- end match templates -->
<!--  non toccare -->

    <!--  match/copia tutti i commenti  -->
    <xsl:template match='comment()'>
     <xsl:comment><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:comment>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--  match/copia di eventuali istruzioni <?elementostart> ecc : ovvero eventuali processing istructions -->
    <xsl:template match='processing-instruction()'>
     <xsl:processing-instruction name="{name()}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:processing-instruction>
    </xsl:template>


    <!--  funzione identità : match/copia di tutti tag che contengono testo e non, compresi i CDATA :
     "*" seleziona solo i tag,   
     node() seleziona tutti i nodi testo, non testo ed i cdata, 
     @* seleziona tutti gli attributi, 
     | => OR
     i commenti non vengono copiati, vedere template comment()

     -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

<!-- end non toccare -->    


<!-- definizione templates per sostituzione variabili -->
    <xsl:template name="eventotmp">
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
            <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/TITOLO</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
    <!--        <xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/TITOLO"/>  -->
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="decorrenzatmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:element name="fo:block">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$DECORRENZA^')"/>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/DATA_ISCRIZIONE_ESTESA</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$DECORRENZA^')"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="descrizionetmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>RAGIONE: </xsl:text> -->
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^')"/>
            <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
                <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^')"/>
<!--        <xsl:text>RAGIONE: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE"/> -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="tipologiatmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>TIPOLOGIA: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$TIPOLOGIA_INFORMAZIONE_PRIVILEGIATA^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/TIPO_INFORMAZIONE_PRIVILEGIATA</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
<!--        <xsl:text>TIPOLOGIA: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/TIPO_INFORMAZIONE_PRIVILEGIATA"/> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$TIPOLOGIA_INFORMAZIONE_PRIVILEGIATA^')"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ruolotmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>RUOLO: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$RUOLO^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/RUOLO_BREVE</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$RUOLO^')"/>
<!--        <xsl:text>RUOLO: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/RUOLO_BREVE"/> -->
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>



    <xsl:template name="funzionetmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>FUNZIONE: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$FUNZIONE^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/FUNZIONE_BREVE</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
<!--        <xsl:text>FUNZIONE: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/FUNZIONE_BREVE"/> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$FUNZIONE^')"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>




    <xsl:template name="nrarticolotmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>NR. ARTICOLO: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$NR_ARTICOLO^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/NR_ARTICOLO</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
<!--        <xsl:text>NR. ARTICOLO: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/NR_ARTICOLO"/> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$NR_ARTICOLO^')"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="codinfotmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>CODICE INFORMAZIONE: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$CODICE_INFORMAZIONE^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/CODICE_INFORMAZIONE</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$CODICE_INFORMAZIONE^')"/>
<!--        <xsl:text>CODICE INFORMAZIONE: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/CODICE_INFORMAZIONE"/> -->
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="ciptmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>CODICE CIP: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$CIP^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/CODICE_PRATICA</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$CIP^')"/>
<!--        <xsl:text>CIP:</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/CODICE_PRATICA"/> -->
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="protocollotmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--        <xsl:text>PROTOCOLLO: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$PROTOCOLLO^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/PROTOCOLLO</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$PROTOCOLLO^')"/>
<!--        <xsl:text>PROTOCOLLO: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/PROTOCOLLO"/> -->
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="emittentetmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--    <xsl:text>EMITTENTE: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$EMITTENTE^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/EMITTENTE_ESTESA</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>

        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$EMITTENTE^')"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="areacompetenzatmp">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:element name="fo:block">
<!--    <xsl:text>EMITTENTE: </xsl:text> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text,'$$AREA_COMPETENZA^')"/>
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
            <xsl:attribute name="select">/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/AREA_COMPETENZA</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
<!--        <xsl:text>EMITTENTE: </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/EMITTENTE_ESTESA"/> -->
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-after($text,'$$AREA_COMPETENZA^')"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I use this template only, like the last of chain substitutions (pipeline). Why doens't get the same expected for RUOLO and DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE?

Thanks

Roby

---

Thanks @JLRishe 
It works for replacing but, it doesn't consider the   so all text appear in the same line without CARRIAGE RETURN preservation.. XSL FO Input look likes:

```
 <fo:page-sequence master-reference="all-pages"><fo:static-content flow-name="page-header"><fo:block font-size="small" text-align="center" space-before="0.5in" space-before.conditionality="retain"/></fo:static-content><fo:static-content flow-name="page-footer"><fo:block font-size="small" text-align="center" space-after="0.5in" space-after.conditionality="retain">- <fo:page-number/> -</fo:block></fo:static-content><fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body"><fo:block role="html:body">
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">ISCRIZIONE PRIVILEGIATA</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p"><fo:block role="html:br"/>Comunicazione relativa all'Elenco dele persone che hanno accesso alle informazioni privilegiate istituito ai sensi del</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">$$EVENTO^</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">Con la presente Le comunichiamo che in data $$DECORRENZA^ è stato iscritto nel ..) (“MAR”) e dalla relativa disciplina di attuazione contenuta nel Regolamento di esecuzione .. – con riferimento a:</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p"> </fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">Tipologia informazione privilegiata $$TIPOLOGIA_INFORMAZIONE_PRIVILEGIATA^ e per il ruolo $$RUOLO^, funzione $$FUNZIONE^ da lei ricoperta per la specifica informazione privilegiata con la seguente motivazione $$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^.</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">Si chiede di far preciso riferimento alla “Procedura per la gestione del Registro delle Persone che hanno accesso a Informazioni Privilegiate” (la “Procedura”) che risulta in vigore che risulta consultabile sul sito internet della Società al seguente indirizzo</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p"> </fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">Per la nozione di informazione privilegiata si rinvia all’articolo 7 MAR riprodotto in allegato alla presente, nonché alla procedura denominata “Procedura per la gestione interna e per la comunicazione al pubblico di Informazioni xxx” adottata dalla Società che parimenti risulta consultabile sul sito internet all’indirizzo sopra indicato.</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p"> </fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">$$EMITTENTE^</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">$$CIP^</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">$$PROTOCOLLO^</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">$$AREA_COMPETENZA^</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">Per presa visione e ritiro di copia</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">Data ...........................................</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p">Firma .....................................................</fo:block> 
  <fo:block space-before="1em" space-after="1em" role="html:p"> </fo:block>
 </fo:block></fo:flow></fo:page-sequence>
</fo:root>
```

Comment: When matching templates for a particular node, it can only match one template. Not several. The template for `$$FUNZIONE^` is further down than the one for `$$DESCRIZIONE_IZCRIZIONE^` and `$$RUOLO^` so that is the one that is used. What XSLT engine are you using to execute this XSLT? Also, please provide some sample input XML that can be used to observe the problem you're having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that when applying templates to nodes, a single node can only be matched by one template. Since your template for FUNZIONE has a higher precedence than the one for RUOLO or DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE (because it appears later than them), that is the one that is being used.

The solution is to use a recursive approach that progressively replaces placeholders until there are no more to replace. The following does this and also eliminates a lot of the duplication in your XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" exclude-result-prefixes="fo vr"
                xmlns:vr="my-variables"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <vr:substitutions>
    <substitution key="$$FUNZIONE^" path="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/FUNZIONE_BREVE" />
    <substitution key="$$RUOLO^" path="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/RUOLO_BREVE" />
    <substitution key="$$CODICE_INFORMAZIONE^" path="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/CODICE_INFORMAZIONE" />
    <substitution key="$$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^" path="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE" />
  </vr:substitutions>

  <xsl:variable name="substitutions" select="document('')/*/vr:substitutions/substitution" />

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fo:block[contains(., '$$')] | fo:inline[contains(., '$$')]">
    <fo:block>
      <xsl:call-template name="PerformSubstitutions">
        <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </fo:block>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="PerformSubstitutions">
    <xsl:param name="text" />
    <xsl:variable name="substitution" select="$substitutions[contains($text, @key)]" />

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$substitution">
        <!-- Recursively call PerformSubstitutions on portion before placeholder-->
        <xsl:call-template name="PerformSubstitutions">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-before($text, $substitution/@key)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <!-- Insert xsl:value-of -->
        <xsl:element name="xsl:value-of">
          <xsl:attribute name="select">
            <xsl:value-of select="$substitution/@path"/>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
        <!-- Recursively call PerformSubstitutions on portion after placeholder-->
        <xsl:call-template name="PerformSubstitutions">
          <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $substitution/@key)" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <!-- No substitutions found. Just output the text -->
        <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You can handle as many placeholders as you need by adding more elements to the `<vr:substitutions>` section.

When run on this input XML:

```
<n xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <fo:inline>Some text $$FUNZIONE^ and $$RUOLO^ other text $$DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE^ </fo:inline>
  <fo:block>Some more text $$CODICE_INFORMAZIONE^ yay.</fo:block>
</n>
```

The output is:

```
<n xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <fo:block>Some text <xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/FUNZIONE_BREVE" /> and <xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/RUOLO_BREVE" /> other text <xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/DESCRIZIONE_ISCRIZIONE" /> </fo:block>
  <fo:block>Some more text <xsl:value-of select="/root/ddx[@id='rsSelect']/r/CODICE_INFORMAZIONE" /> yay.</fo:block>
</n>
```

Comment: It works for replacing but, it doesn't consider the <fo:block> </fo:block> so all text appear in the same line without CARRIAGE RETURN preservation..

Comment: @robyp7 Please _edit your question_ to specify a sample input and the expected output for that input.